# FamaFrench, FamaMacBeth or Panel regression?

Tags: time-series, regression, fama-french, mutual-fund, paneldata

I hope my question is not extremely trivial.
I want to analyse the performance of mutual funds using the Fama-French model.
My dependent variable is the return of mutual funds (varying over time and across observations).
On the right hand side, I have the Fama French factors (constant across observations and varying over time).
I did not find a clear cut answer to my doubt. Once I run the regression at fund-by-fund level, should I also perform the Fama MacBeth regression?
Whould it be wrong to run a panel regression if I can include on the right hand side also a variable related to the Rating of the fund? In that case, I would have only one regressor that is varying over observations in my regression.
Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: 'analyse the performance' is a bit vague. depending on what you want to calculate exactly, everything you listed could be the way to go